# Can any body please tell me why my query take forever to run?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

Can anybody please tell me why my query takes forever to run? I want to make sure nothing wrong with my query that slow down the process.

```
 WITH TradeIn AS 
    (
        SELECT  CONVERT(ID.DateCreated, DATE) 'Invoice Date' , ID.InvoiceIDByStore ,
                ID.InvoicedAt , ID.EmployeeName , ID.TenderedBy , ID.CustomerName ,
                ID.ProductIdentifier , ID.ProductName , ID.SerialNumber ,
                ID.Quantity , ID.TotalPrice
            FROM  simplymacstaging.productdetail ID
            LEFT JOIN  simplymacstaging.productmasterlist PM 
                  ON PM.ProductSKU = ID.ProductIdentifier
            WHERE  CONVERT(ID.DateCreated, DATE) >= '2014-01-01'
              AND  CONVERT(ID.DateCreated, DATE) <= '2014-12-31'
              AND  ID.InvoicedAt IN ('100 Park City', '101 Orem', '102 Fort Union',
                        '105 St. George', '106 Foothill'
                          )
              AND  DefaultVendorName IN ('Simply Mac Trade In', 'Phobio')
              OR  ProductIdentifier IN ('ISATNS000001','ISATRB000003',
                        'ISPHNR000007','COMINS001595','COMIRB001597','ISPHNS000003',
                        'COMINS001415','ISPHRB000004','COMIRB001416','ISPHTL000006',
                        'IABUAP000004','IABUAP000003','MIMICE000035','MIMICE000426',
                        'MIMICE000427','IABUAP000006','COMIAP000007','COMICE000011')
    ) 
SELECT  *
    FROM  simplymacstaging.productdetail PD
    INNER JOIN  TradeIn TD  ON TD.InvoiceIDByStore = PD.InvoiceIDByStore
    WHERE  CONVERT(PD.DateCreated, DATE) >= '2014-01-01'
      AND  CONVERT(PD.DateCreated, DATE) <= '2014-12-31'
```

Any idea how to improve this or make it faster?

Thank you so much

Comment: First of all, put parentheses in the `WHERE` clause to group your conditions. When you combine `AND` and `OR`, the default precedence is almost never what you really want.

Comment: If you have an index on the `DateCreated` column, it's not being used because you can't use an index whan calling a function.

Comment: It won't make any difference to performance, but you can use `BETWEEN` when testing if something is in a range of dates.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`? Inner join is usually faster.

Comment: In order to help with query performance questions, we need to know all the indexes on the table and what `EXPLAIN` says about the query. Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

- `OR` often prevents the use of any indexes.
- Don't convert dates to `DATE` -- I assume `DateCreated` is already a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, which would work fine without the `CONVERT()`.
- After getting rid of `CONVERT`, `INDEX(InvoiceIDByStore, DateCreated)` on `PD` is likely to help a lot.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see if you have suitable index(es).
- Please qualify all column names (when using `JOIN`) so we know which table they are in (eg: `DefaultVendorName`)
- Please provide `EXPLAIN`.
- I don't see the need for `WITH`; it seems like the big `SELECT` in the `WITH` could be turned into a 'derived table'.  It would be interesting to see if the `EXPLAIN` stays the same.